# IIS asking for log in credentials

Tags: iis

I have this Windows Server installed on a virtual machine, and I have a website on IIS of that virtual machine for some testing purposes. The problem here is, that everytime I want to acces to the website, the site asks me for some username and password. At first I didn't know why, I tried using the sites login but it didn't worked. Then I used the virtual machine's log in and that's how it worked. My question here is, how do I disable it? The site is in a virtual directory, and I had it located on My documents. At first I thought it was that but when I changed the security of the "My Documents" folder to shared, it still keeps asking me for credentials. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This likely has to do with the authentication settings of the site within IIS. Do you have Windows Authentication turned on for the site via IIS? Here is a good link that should help solve your issue:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/123890/site-deployed-in-iis-7-is-always-asking-for-username-and-pas.aspx