# published asp.net keeps asking for login credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

I am trying to published a test web-site to a hosting service, which I believe is running IIS 8.0. I used the visual studio 2015 Build->Publish  and setup an ftp profile.

The web-site is published but it only works if I enter credentials at the root level. In my profile I have chosen release build, but the problem is the persists whether I use Debug or Release.

I looked at this thread but it did not help.

[IIS asking for log in credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368619/iis-asking-for-log-in-credentials)

Since web-site is hosted on a hosting service, I have no control over the IIS 8.0. It is something that can be fixed remotely?

Here is the web.config file:

```
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpModules>
          <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
        </httpModules>
      </system.web>
      <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
          <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
          <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
      </system.codedom>
      <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules>
          <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
          <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        </modules>
      </system.webServer>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
      </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

The sample program, which is extremely simple just rendering one button:

```
    namespace testwebsite
    {
        public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                UnobtrusiveValidationMode = UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;

                string method = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().ToString();
                Debug.WriteLine(method + "called!");
            }

            protected void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string method = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().ToString();
                Debug.WriteLine(method + "called!");
            }
        }
    }
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only I got it to work was to copy this section from a Web.Config the hosting company had originally on the default template web-site (I changed the key, but it is just lengthy AES key)

```
    <system.webServer>
        <!--No sure why I have to have this-->
        <security>
          <authentication>
            <!--How did this get generated?-->
            <anonymousAuthentication password="[enc:AesProvider:3436xsIasdj8M264Fs73<somelengthykey>DFHDFGlrrh345YaOXmhpI=:enc]" />
          </authentication>
        </security>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        ...
    </system.webServer>
```

Yet, I have no idea how this AesProvider password was generated. Anyone knows if this can get generated from the asp control panel? I still don't see a way.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the authentication type to `Anonymous Authentication` by changing the web config.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
       <authorization>
         <allow users="?"/>
       </authorization>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: did not make a difference for me but I got it to work in a different way, see my own answer. There is still something I don't understand